# Foundation 6 flex grid and predefined floats

Tags: zurb-foundation, flexbox, zurb-foundation-6

I like the idea of `flex-grid` and was wondering if I'm using it correctly.  I started a build using Foundation 6 / SASS and did `@include foundation-flex-grid;`

While building a basic page I noticed in my DevTools that certain items from the Kitchen sink are using styles on items that have their displays set to `block` and `float` on them.

### Example: `.title-bar`

```
<div class="title-bar">
        <div class="title-bar-left">
          <button class="menu-icon" type="button"></button>
          <span class="title-bar-title">Foundation</span>
        </div>
        <div class="title-bar-right">
          <button class="menu-icon" type="button"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The elements `.title-bar-left` and `.title-bar-right` have corresponding floats on them.  I know that floats are unnecessary in flex-grid.

### My question(s):

1. Should I keep building away using `flex-grid` or should I be doing
   something extra to remove/replace those styles ahead of time?
2. It seems to me that the [Kitchen Sink on the Foundation Site](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/kitchen-sink.html) is
   tailored for the normal grid, is it safe to use these elements in
   `flex-grid` with little modification, or will it require lots of
   rewriting of SASS/CSS?

Answer (score 0):

For #2, 'Kitchen-sink' can pass `true` to turn on flex-grid like so:

`@include foundation-everything(true);`

They might have added this sometime in F6.1 or F6.2; official docs don't reflect this, but I put in a [PR](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/8336) to.

For #1, might be more of a bug question than a best-usage issue, perhaps you should [submit](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+flex+menu) it?